# JavaScript script is not loading

Tags: javascript, html, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to make my HTML and JavaScript code really organized so i'm all the JavaScript code is in different files.

When trying to insert the code into the HTML page it doesn't work:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<body>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="facebook.js" type="javascript" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**this is facebook.js:**

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    // init the FB JS SDK
    FB.init({
        appId      : 'APP_ID',                     // App ID from the app dashboard
        status     : true,                                 // Check Facebook Login status
        xfbml      : true                                  // Look for social plugins on the page
    });

    //subscribe event for facebook login
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function(response) {
        alert(response.status);
    });

};

// Load the SDK asynchronously
(function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

When i'm using the exact same script inside my html - it works great..
what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: And your console is blank?  What browser are you using, and where is this script located in relation to your file?  Also, the correct 'type' attribute is `text/javascript`.

Comment: The console says nothing..
it was the text\javascript part that was missing... write it as answer so i could accept it :) thanks

Comment: Writing a comprehensive answer, as requested.

Comment: Sorry that took so long, wanted to make sure I gave an accurate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I noted in my comment above, one of the correct values when dealing with a javascript content type is `text/javascript`, as "noted" in the [w3c spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html#adef-type-SCRIPT).

I said above it is 'one' of the correct values; this is due to the MIME-type listing specified [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-content-type), and accessed [here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:ftp://ftp.isi.edu/in-notes/iana/assignments/media-types/)(as a note, the MIME-type listing currently appears to be down, so the above page is of a web archive); the MIME-type listing specifies that 'text/javascript' is obsolete, and by clicking the relevant [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4329)(4329), it appears the now-correct MIME-type is `application/javascript`.

Comment: Of course, I could be wrong, but that's what I managed to find.

Answer (score 2):

Try `type="text/javascript"` in the script tag.

Also, is your .js file in the same folder as your .html file? If you've put the JavaScript in a folder you will need to do something like this:

`<script src="FolderName/facebook.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`